# Ajax loading of Page with jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am new to jQuery and want to know what's that method called when clicking a link loads something with `domain.com/#/this` using Ajax. Something similar like `http://cargocollective.com/#/featuredprojects`. It also happens when you go to a link directly and it opens (ajaxly) that page.

A link to some tutorial on how to do this would be extremely helpful.
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `#` marks, it sounds like you're talking about a history plug-in. There are several, of which [this one](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) is probably the better-known. More accurately, it sounds like a history plug-in combined with [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls (either direct `ajax` calls or one of the convenience wrappers, like [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)).

Alternately, you might also look at "tabs" plug-ins, like [the one in jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).